# How to align to text blocks differently inline in the same containing element?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` element containing two blocks of text. One block is aligned in the center of the element, and I would like to align the second block to the right.

The page on which I am trying to do this can be seen [here](http://perso.citi-lab.fr/mselva/).

I have tried creating an inner `<div>` element in the footer with floating the second block of text and applying `float: right` to it. The problem with this solution is that the text first (centered) text element is now aligned in the center of the remaining space, minus the width of the floated `<div>`, instead of centered in the containing element.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
<div id="footer">
      <div id="Valid">
          Valid <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">HTML</a>
          and <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a>
      </div>
  <div id="modified">
         Last modified ...
      </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the two text blocks to display in the positions I desire?

EDIT: I am setting up an http://jsfiddle.net/ example (suggested SSCCE seems down at the moment)

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/vjmVc/ I also tried with two nested div elements without success

Comment: What do you mean by 'a first text...and a second one'? What's your *actual* ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML?

Comment: http://perso.citi-lab.fr/mselva/ in the footer I want to add a last modified element on the right

Comment: Please: add your (relevant) HTML to the question. We're happy to help, but please don't force us to have to put even more effort into it; help *us* to help *you*.

Comment: And stop vertically aligning stuff using `<br>` tags

Comment: Also it's not clear what you've tried so far. I'd say that using a single DIV tag is never enough to achieve what you want to do. You can try with TABLE first, then convert it to CSS. - this might be helpful, too: http://cssdesignpatterns.com/

Comment: you guys are impatient, less than half a hour of his question and everyone is downvoating...thats stupid, wait a little longer

Comment: I'll edit the question in a few minutes

Comment: @Ark: LOL. Here is your patients. The closed the question.

Comment: There is no text-color: red; it should be color: red; Also #valid {text-align: center;} since there is elemnet by that id in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the right part of taking up the space you can position it `absolute`. The only thing you would have to keep in mind in that case is set the positioning of the container element (footer) to `relative`: http://jsfiddle.net/vjmVc/1/

Also keep in mind that when people have a small screen the two element may overlap at some point using this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was asking for the cleanest solution to do that, have you got a "better" solution ?

Comment: Internet (and my English) are really bad for communicating. I am saying that my solution is wrong (as you stated for small screens) so I am asking if you have another way to solve that ?*

Comment: And one more question, what is really strange to me in MY solution is that the footer div is effectively 100% large (the purple background crosses all the page) but the text is not centered according to this background size ...

Comment: i accepted the answer but would be interested in a solution fixing the issue of small screen you mentionned

Comment: I have been tinkering a bit with it some more. But I couldn't get it done just like that. However what you could do to also be able to have good support for smaller sizes is use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) and change them to be displayed underneath each other for smaller sizes.

Answer (score 1):

display: inline; float: right; n the elements inside the div
but this way you ill need to invert the order of the texts.

Answer (score -1):

First, Add a proper DOCTYPE. You page is loading in quirks mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

For the text

```
#footer
{
text-align: right;
}
```

For the alignment

```
#all
{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

EDIT

```
#footer
{
position: relative;
}

#modified
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I already have the doctype and I am able to align text on the center. Now what I want is another text aligned to the right

Comment: If u have a PROPER doctype, than I am Santa Clause. Here is your doctype - DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" and your document is loading in quirks mode.

Comment: Hello santa clause, why you didnt gimme that bike last year?

Comment: @Ark: LOL. Sorry about that mate. I will make sure this year.